# Creating Automator Quick Action to Extract (and Move) Media Files From Subfolders to New Folder (in Parent Directory)

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, filesystem, spotlight

I have an audio recording device that puts all files from any given capture into its own folder. (This includes all channels of the recording plus a metadata document.)

Typically, I navigate to the parent directory and use the Spotlight search (with the scope set to that folder) to locate the files I want, using the criteria: "Kind - is - Music." In a second Finder window, I create a folder just for the audio files (ex. "AudioFiles") inside the parent directory (at the same level as the folders containing the individual recordings). Finally, I drag the Spotlight search results (from the first window) into "AudioFiles" (in the second window).

I am trying to create an equivalent quick-action workflow to automate this set of actions. The one I built is shown below. It sort of works, but it copies the files instead of just moving them (which may also explain why it works slower than expected). Thanks in advance.

[image: Quick action workflow]